# how to get the count in r till it meet a specific value and continue

Tags: r, for-loop

I need to write an R program that, given a vector, will return another vector giving the number of elements from each position in the input vector to the occurrence in the input vector of a specified value. For example, if the specified value is 0, then with:

```
input : x<-c(1,1,0,1,1,1,0)

desired output<- (2,1,0,3,2,1,0)
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What happens if the specified value does not appear to the right of a particular position?  Or are we to assume the specified value always appears as the last element?

Comment: Not really. I need the count of values till it meets a zero.The last element doesn't have to be a zero always. In the above example the first element  has 2 other elements to pass (including the 1st) to reach a zero. The second element has 1 position left. When the zero is reached the 4th element has 3 positions to meet the next zero. etc. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try

```
library(data.table)
ave(x, rleid(x), FUN= function(x) rev(seq_along(x)))*x
#[1] 2 1 0 3 2 1 0
```

---

We could also use `rle` from `base R`

```
rl <- inverse.rle(within.list(rle(x), values <- seq_along(values)))
ave(x, rl, FUN=function(x) rev(seq_along(x)))*x
#[1] 2 1 0 3 2 1 0
```

Comment: Many thanks.However, I get the following error "Error in interaction(...) : could not find function "rleid"" when I try this.

Comment: @nicky It is in `data.table`.  You may need to install `data.table` if you don't have installed it and then load `library(data.table)`

Comment: @nicky Updated with a base R option.